# Visual Studio Code vs Powershell ISE: Getting Intellisense suggestion pop-up in terminal window in VSC?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make the move over from Powershell ISE to Visual Studio Code, but I'm struggling with the terminal.

[In the script editor, when configured for ISE mode (or by using the extension), the suggestion window for cmdlets and their parameters pops up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yBh2.png)

However, in the terminal the suggestions seem to only be available in-line using tab and I'm having to cycle through.

Is there a way to get the same behaviour working in the integrated console? I'm not sure if this is an ISE feature only that isn't available in VSC, or that I just have bad practise and should be using tab instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, trying hard to be a bit more modern!

Comment: You won't get the same behavior in the terminal in VSC - ISE's terminal is specifically implemented to support all the visual hints, whereas the VSC terminal just shows a regular prompt (which in turn means you can host bash/cmd/powershell/zsh in the same pane).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen drats, thanks for confirming!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's not much to be answered - OP is just gonna have to "bite the lemon" as they say :)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible! New practises will be implemented :)